# Microsoft VisualFoxPro 9 silent install with Ansible

Tags: ansible, microsoft, visual-foxpro

I need to automate Microsoft Visual FoxPro 9 installation via Ansible, but it seems like VFP9 installer does not have silent install mode.

(please note that I am installing MS Visual FoxPro 9, not a FoxPro application, so suggestions like [this one](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/194/Q194572/) will not work).

Did I miss something and there IS a way to do a silent/unattended install for VFP9?

> **Installer details:**
>
> [image: Installer details]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. setup.exe supports /UnattendFile option that uses an .ini file with pre-configured installation parameters - create it according to your needs.
2. Installer should be run from local elevated prompt (psexec).

Ansible task will look like this:

```
- name: Install FoxPro (via PsExec)
  win_psexec:
    command: "cmd.exe /c cd {{ install_folder }}\\FoxPro\\software\\setup\\ && setup.exe /fulllog /UnattendFile unattended.ini"
    executable: "{{ install_folder }}\\FoxPro\\PsExec.exe"
    elevated: yes
    system: yes
    nobanner: yes
```